# Iterate and Set Ruby Object Instance Variables

Tags: ruby, setter, instance-variables

I'm looking for a way to iterate through a Ruby object's instance variables, and set them individually (from a provided hash) using a generic setter.  I am assuming I can iterate through them directly in a method and simply set each individually.

Here is my object instance, u:

```
u = #<Waffle:0x00007fc6b1145530 
    @id=nil,
    @alpha="",
    @bravo="",
    @charlie="",
    @delta=nil,
    @echo=nil,
    @status=new>
```

I would like to populate it with a given hash, h:

```
h = {
    "id"=>"141",
     "alpha"=>"Muccahiya""
     "bravo"=>"$2a$10$xR2g",
     "charlie"=>"2018-02-21 10:41:56-05",
     "delta"=>"2018-02-05 18:17:16.752606-05",
     "echo"=>"wobbly",
     "status"=>"active"
}
```

This is the method I have and it is throwing this error:

```
def to_obj(h)
    self.instance_variables.each do |i|
        self.i = h[i.sub('@','')]
    end
end
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
3: from /users/rich/app.rb:31:in `<main>'
2: from /Library/WebServer/Documents/dingbat/models/waffle.rb:240:in `to_obj'
1: from /Library/WebServer/Documents/dingbat/models/waffle.rb:240:in `each'
/Library/WebServer/Documents/dingbat/models/waffle.rb:241:in `block in to_obj': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

`self.instance_variables` is indeed an array of symbols.

I am thinking that an object can set its `instance_variables` given a hash.  This can't be difficult.

Comment: You want `instance_variable_set` method

Answer (score 4):

```
def to_obj(h)
  h.each{|k, v| instance_variable_set("@{k}", v)}
end
```

If you want to set a value only if such instance variable is defined, then do:

```
def to_obj(h)
  h.each do
    |k, v|
    next unless instance_variable_defined?("@{k}")
    instance_variable_set("@{k}", v)
  end
end
```

Comment: For security reasons, I'm iterating the object's ivars and setting accordingly from the hash, instead of the other way around.  Cheers

Comment: @Rich_F: could you elaborate on that? This inversion does not add _any_ security.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev iterating the instance variables (instead of the hash keys) ensures that you can only set existing instance variables.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The provided hash could be larger than the array of instance_variables I want to actually modify.  So if I qualify the instance_variables, I can only set those, instead of having the hash take the lead.

Comment: @Stefan: yes, but if something were to set an "unknown" instance variable, it wouldn't be used by anything (except maybe reflection-based serialization or something). Plus, this mass-assign is "unpredicable" (depends on what instance variables in the object are "alive" at the moment)

Comment: @Rich_F: if you whitelist "settable" instance variables (of which we have no evidence in this thread) - then yes. but in this case you might just as well filter hash keys. It's the whitelisting that adds security, not the inversion.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `instance_variables` seems to be that whitelist.

Comment: @Stefan: if so, it's a pretty fragile whitelist, as I said :)

Comment: @Stefan: after giving it some thought, I can recognize this as a valid approach in some cases. I wasn't able to come up with even one of such cases, though :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It's not fragile at all.  I'm iterating through them, and nothing else.  I can further filter afterwards.  If it's run from the hash, then it might find that throwing a pair at the object has nothing to do, so there's an error.  i.e.: If h had `{"tango"=>"12345"}` as well, it would result in an error as there is no @tango defined.  Second, that's what methods are for.  I don't toss things at objects: I get objects to ask for them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm also trying to abstract a reusable method as well.  Filtering the incoming hash every time pretty much requires me to customize the application every time.  So nothing has been achieved, not to mention loads more coding, and much testing and troubleshooting, all avoided using the method technique.  In any case, I was after the ivar set.